# CrudRepository obtener una lista usando 3 tablas

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy usando java 8, springboot JPA, extends CrudRepository.

Tengo dos entidades con los siguientes atributos:

```
public class Producto {
@Id
private String ean; 
private double formato;
private String titulo;
private double precioSugerido;

@JoinColumn 
@ManyToOne 
private Categoria categoria;

@JoinColumn
@ManyToOne
private Marca marca;

private String estado;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Producto_cliente", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "producto_ean"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_nombre"))
private Set<Cliente> Cliente = new HashSet<>();
```

y

```
@Entity 
public class Link {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @JoinColumn 
    @ManyToOne 
    private Producto producto;
    
    @JoinColumn 
    @ManyToOne 
    private Etailer etailer;
    
    private String link;
    
    private String estado;
    
    private String formato;
```

Quisiera hacer una lista de objetos Link filtrado por a) un etailer, b) estado y c) Productos que sean del Cliente "X".

A y B lo resolví así:

```
public List<Link> findByEtailerAndEstado (Etailer etailer, String estado);
```

En el Repository de Link.

Pero No sé cómo hacer para filtrar esa lista por los productos que pertenecen a un cliente, siendo que la relación al ser manyToMany está en una tabla pivot producto_cliente.

Alguna idea?

Para que se entienda más en MySql la consulta es así:

```
Select link.id, link.estado, link, link.etailer_id, producto.ean
from producto, link, producto_cliente
where link.producto_ean = producto.ean
and producto.ean = producto_cliente.producto_ean
and etailer_id = 1
and producto_cliente.cliente_nombre = 'Beiersdorf'
and link.estado = 'Activo';
```

Answer (score 0):

Natalia, podés usar la anotación `@Query` para ejecutar la consulta en SQL nativo. En tu caso, podrías hacer algo así:

```
@Query("Select * FROM link l
from producto, link, producto_cliente
LEFT JOIN producto p ON p.ean = l.producto_ean
LEFT JOIN producto_cliente pc ON pc.producto_ean = p.ean
and etailer_id = ?1
and producto_cliente.cliente_nombre = ?2
and link.estado = ?3;", nativeQuery= true)
public List<Link> findByProductosByCliente(Etailer etailer, String nombreCliente, String estado)
```

(verificá que los nombres de las columnas en los join sean correctos).